# How to express that a function, upon returning, no longer references its pass-by-reference or pass-by-pointer parameters?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, reference, compiler-construction

In C++, it is common for functions to have pass-by-reference or pass-by-pointer parameters, the latter of which also exists in C. (For convenience, I will only talk about pointers in the following discussions. But the problem exists for both.) The problem is, will the function store the pointers in some places with longer extent than the function call and use the pointers after the function returns? If yes, the caller of the function has to hold the values being pointed by the pointers until the pointers expire.

In C++, `shared_ptr` can be a solution, but with noticeable heap-memory and thread-safe overheads. `unique_ptr` isn't applicable either since the caller wants to retain the ownership.

What I am looking for is some language construct like `const` that can be enforced at compile-time, without incurring any run-time overheads. Let's say its name is `short_lived`. A `short_lived T* ptr` is a pointer `ptr` to a value of type `T`. A function receiving `ptr` as its parameter shouldn't store the value of `ptr` to any places with longer extent than the current function call (e.g. a global variable), either in current function or any sub-functions called from inside the current function. The latter "sub-functions" constraint means that `ptr` shouldn't be passed into sub-functions as a non-`short_lived` pointer. Since the extent of variables is more of a runtime property, for simple implementation, the compiler can forbid all assignments from `short_lived` pointers in the receiving function.

Has the above conceived behavior been supported in contemporary C/C++ standards? If not, what are the reasons?

Thanks!

Comment: As C and C++ are very different languages, you should pick one and only tag for that language.

Comment: This requires a more sophisticated type system than what's in C++ (not to mention C). Have you looked at Rust?

Comment: There is nothing similar to what you ask for in C++, maybe there are some code-analysis out there that can help you with that. I'd say that the rule of thumb is opposite to what you ask for: if a function takes a pointer or a reference, that functions should not store it/use it outside its lifetime. If the function needs to do so, you should wrap the parameters into either a `unique_ptr` (if you can) or another empty struct like `owner_ptr` (see the GSL) to clearly indicates that you're going to store the pointer/reference for later use and take/share ownership of it.

Comment: C does not have passing by reference in C++ sense

Comment: If you need anything like this it means that your project design is very poor. You need to rethink it. It will get more complicated when you start learning to multitask.

Comment: References in C++ are _yet another language feature hiding important information_, here their nature as a pointer. I can be wrong, but they are hardly more than an additional irritating syntax to use pointers and are hard to be set to `nullptr`. -- Anyway, C++ as a language does not support this kind of life time checks. And C does not, too.

Comment: are you looking for reference counting?

Comment: I have updated the question to talk about C and C++ in separate sentences to make it clear that pass-by-reference doesn't exist in C. Thanks for your feedbacks!

Comment: "are you looking for reference counting?" No. I am looking for a parameter qualifier as a contract between the caller and the callee.

Comment: "If you need anything like this it means that your project design is very poor." --- I don't think so. Perhaps I didn't explain my ideas clearly enough. I am looking for a language construct, a qualifier, like ```const```, that expresses compile-time attribute that helps function callers. Does ```const``` indicate bad design?

Comment: In modern C++, a borrowed pointer is just `T*`. This is only a convention of course, not something that the compiler can enforce. A C++ type system is not powerful enough for that.